# button to create a new div which is already existing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<form>    
<fieldset>
      <legend>DownTime</legend>
      <div id="downtime">
      Start of DownTime:
      <input type="time" name="startdowntime">
      Reason:
      <select type="text" name="reason">
      <option>Reason1</option>
      <option>Reason2</option>
      <option>Reason3</option>
      <option>Reason4</option>
      </select>
      End of DownTime:
      <input type="time" name="stoptdowntime">
      <br>
      </div>
      </br>
      <button type="button">Add another DownTime</button><br>
      </fieldset>
      <br>
      <fieldset>
</form>
```

[image]

I need to add a function to the button I created? Using the button I want to add 'n' numbers of downtime entries.

Comment: If you do this you need to change this: `<div id="downtime">` with this: `<div class="downtime">`. The ID must be unique so if you need to create multiple instances you can not use an id in the way you are doing. You can use Jquery to clone the element and append it to the dom every time you push the button.

Answer (score -2):

```
<form>    
<fieldset>
      <legend>DownTime</legend>
     <div id="parentdiv">
      <div class="downtime">
      Start of DownTime:
      <input type="time" name="startdowntime">
      Reason:
      <select type="text" name="reason">
      <option>Reason1</option>
      <option>Reason2</option>
      <option>Reason3</option>
      <option>Reason4</option>
      </select>
      End of DownTime:
      <input type="time" name="stoptdowntime">
      <br>
      </div>
      </br>
      </div>
      <button type="button" id="addbtn">Add another DownTime</button><br>

      <fieldset>
</form>
```

Via Jquery  and ES6:-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var html = `
   <div class="downtime">
          Start of DownTime:
          <input type="time" name="startdowntime">
          Reason:
          <select type="text" name="reason">
          <option>Reason1</option>
          <option>Reason2</option>
          <option>Reason3</option>
          <option>Reason4</option>
          </select>
          End of DownTime:
          <input type="time" name="stoptdowntime">
          <br>
          </div>
          </br>
`;
$("#addbtn").click(function(e){
    $("#parentdiv").append(html);
});

</script>
```

Comment: This will cause duplicate `ID's`... ID's should be unique and to be hones this is a terrible way of recreating those elements.

Comment: I have already pointed this issue in my comment, You should first read what is written before you post an answer

Comment: sorry..now i have edited my answer..sir if it is terrible way then please guide proper way

Comment: @RajeshPatel I will when I see the attempt(s) from the OP. I don't just throw out free source code. I like to see that person has tried and willing to help themselves before I attempt to help them further. The key to learning is trying, not copy/pasting and since the point of getting answer from stackoverflow is to learn from them.... I feel it's better to wait for the question to be edited to display the relevant information.

Comment: Ok sir..@NewToJS..let me also know better way..by the way i have not copy pasted it..I have done this in my project so i thought i should post..If you hurt by my answer and after crackford you are the most JS known person than i should say sorry to you

Comment: @RajeshPatel Since you said you're using something just like this for one of your projects I will keep it very similar but make it much cleaner. https://jsfiddle.net/kfdyu4z8/ I hope this helps you Rajesh but I don't think the OP is looking to duplicate the input. I think the OP wants the data from the inputs to be displayed in a div dynamically create via javascript.

Comment: @NewToJS now that's a *"Crackford"* solution!

Comment: @NewToJS hahahahah thats crackford war..why you are using html() method of jquery use innerHTML hahahha..best way

Comment: @RajeshPatel jQuery is already being used so it would make sense to keep the source code small and easy. using innerHTML would mean you cannot use the jQuery selector which doesn't make much sense since jQuery is already being used. Just remember, I'm not the one who caused duplicated ID's in the original answer attempt and your current attempt looks messy and over worked. I thought I would offer you a much cleaner way. Why write those elements out when those elements already exist, why not just select them.... Think about that before trying to act smart with people. Good day sir.